# Converting a List to a Dictionary

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I have this list:

```
list1 = ["a","b","c"]
```

And I need to convert it into a dictionary like this

```
value:{
        a:{
            timestamp: "2015-05-19T14:07:30.423765"
        }
        b:{
            timestamp: "2015-05-19T14:07:30.423765"
        }
        c:{
            timestamp: "2015-05-19T14:07:30.423765"
        }
      }
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Maybe `dict( zip( list1, values ) )`?

Comment: Where's the timestamp coming from? Or do you just mean, repeat whatever value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a dictionary comprehension in Python 2.7+ as follows:

```
list1 = ["a","b","c"]
value = {k: {"timestamp":"2015-05-19T14:07:30.423765"} for k in list1}

print value
```

Giving:

```
{'a': {'timestamp': '2015-05-19T14:07:30.423765'}, 'c': {'timestamp': '2015-05-19T14:07:30.423765'}, 'b': {'timestamp': '2015-05-19T14:07:30.423765'}}
```

Answer (score 4):

This should do it, barring any clarifications of the question:

```
import pprint  # For pretty-printing the dict

your_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']

timestamp = '2015-05-19T14:07:30.423765'

your_dict = {item: {'timestamp': timestamp}) for item in your_list)

pprint.pprint(your_dict)  # Pretty-printing the dict

list1 = ["a","b","c"]
value = {k: {"timestamp":"2015-05-19T14:07:30.423765"} for k in list1}
```

Output:

```
{'a': {'timestamp': '2015-05-19T14:07:30.423765'},
 'b': {'timestamp': '2015-05-19T14:07:30.423765'},
 'c': {'timestamp': '2015-05-19T14:07:30.423765'}}
```

Comment: Doh, I wasn't using dict comprehensions; it's late (early?) :/. Thanks to Martin Evans for reminding me :).